# Use object names as list names in R

Tags: r, list, naming

Of course I could name the objects in my list all manually like this:

```
    #create dfs
    df1<-data.frame(a=sample(1:50,10),b=sample(1:50,10),c=sample(1:50,10))
    df2<-data.frame(a=sample(1:50,9),b=sample(1:50,9),c=sample(1:50,9))
    df3<-data.frame(a=sample(1:50,8),b=sample(1:50,8),c=sample(1:50,8))

    #make them a list
    list.1<-list(df1=df1,df2=df2,df3=df3)
```

But it makes a lot of work if I have let's say 50 objects with long names.
So is there any way to automate this and make the names inside the list the same as the outside objects?

Comment: See also [Can lists be created that name themselves based on input object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can lists be created that name themselves based on input object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the names, then call `mget`.
If there is a pattern to the names of each individual variable, then this is straightforward.

```
var_names <- paste0("df", 1:3)
mget(var_names, envir = globalenv())  #or maybe envir = parent.frame()
```

If the naming system is more complicated, you can use regular expressions to find them, using something like

```
var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^df[[:digit:]]+$")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to name a list with names from the environment that share something, in this case 'df':

```
names(list.1) <- grep("df",ls(),value=TRUE)
```

If you want to push your environment into a list:

```
list.1 <- globalenv()
list.1 <- as.list(list.1)
```

To reverse the process see `?list2env`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the possible duplicate questions' responses:

From the tidyverse, use `tibble:lst`:
https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/lst.html