# Can lists be created that name themselves based on input object names?

Tags: r, list, names

It would be very helpful to me to be able to create an R list object without having to specify the names of each element.  For example:

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 20
a3 <- 1:20

b <- list(a1,a2,a3, inherit.name=TRUE)
> b

[[a1]]
[1] 1

[[a2]]
[1] 20

[[a3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

This would be ideal.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Coincidentally, I just wrote this function.  It looks a lot like @joran's solution, but it tries not to stomp on already-named arguments.

```
namedList <- function(...) {
    L <- list(...)
    snm <- sapply(substitute(list(...)),deparse)[-1]
    if (is.null(nm <- names(L))) nm <- snm
    if (any(nonames <- nm=="")) nm[nonames] <- snm[nonames]
    setNames(L,nm)
}
## TESTING:
a <- b <- c <- 1
namedList(a,b,c)
namedList(a,b,d=c)
namedList(e=a,f=b,d=c)
```

Copied from comments: if you want something from a CRAN package, you can use `Hmisc::llist`:

```
Hmisc::llist(a, b, c, d=a, labels = FALSE)
```

The only apparent difference is that the individual vectors also have names in this case.

Comment: There is also Hmisc::llist eg llist(a1,a2, labels = FALSE). This protects against already-named arguments,

Comment: Thanks so much! I really like this one.  I will implement it in a [package](https://github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/RConcerto/blob/master/Package.R) I am working on

Comment: This will fail if the input arguments are longer than ~60 character because in that case `deparse()` will generate a vector of length >1, and `sapply()` will make a list instead of a character vector.

Answer (score 42):

The `tidyverse` package `tibble` has a function that can do this as well. Try out `tibble::lst`

```
tibble::lst(a1, a2, a3)
# $a1
#  [1] 1
#
# $a2
#  [1] 20
# 
# $a3
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 12):

A random idea:

```
a1<-1
a2<-20
a3<-1:20

my_list <- function(...){
    names <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
    result <- list(...)
    names(result) <- names
    result
}

> my_list(a1,a2,a3)
$a1
[1] 1

$a2
[1] 20

$a3
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

(The idea is stolen from the code in `data.frame`.)

Comment: +1 - This also seems to work: `my_list <- function(...) setNames(list(...), substitute(alist(...)))`

Comment: There is also `Hmisc::llist` eg  `llist(a1,a2, labels = FALSE)`

Answer (score 5):

Another idea ,

```
 sapply(ls(pattern='^a[0-9]'), get)
$a1
[1] 1

$a2
[1] 20

$a3
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Or more simply  `mget(c('a1','a2','a3'))` (`mget`, not `sapply(...,get)`

Comment: @mnel If you're gonna write the names to get the names, just write the names...