# R get objects' names from the list of objects

Tags: r

I try to get an object's name from the list containing this object. I searched through similar questions and find some suggestions about using the `deparse(substitute(object))` formula:

```
> my.list <- list(model.product, model.i, model.add)
> lapply(my.list, function(model) deparse(substitute(model)))
```

and the result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "X[[1L]]"

[[2]]
[1] "X[[2L]]"

[[3]]
[1] "X[[3L]]"
```

whereas I want to obtain:

`[1] "model.product", "model.i", "model.add"`

Thank you in advance for being of some help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write your own `list()` function so it behaves like `data.frame()`, i.e., uses the un-evaluated arg names as entry names:

```
List <- function(...) {
  names <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  setNames(list(...), names)
}

my.list <- List(model.product, model.i, model.add)
```

Then you can just access the names via:

```
names(my.list)
```

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-list-objects-be-created-in-r-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-name/16951524#16951524

Answer (score 3):

```
names(my.list) #..............
```

Oh wait, you didn't actually create names did you? There is actually no "memory" for the list function. It returns a list with the values of its arguments but not from whence they came, unless you add names to the pairlist given as the argument.

Comment: Any idea as to why `my.df <- data.frame(model.product, model.i, model.add)` does populate the names, while `list()` does not? I find it puzzling...

Comment: deep-rooted inconsistency, I think.  R is organic.

Comment: @flodel - `as.list(data.frame(model.product, model.i, model.add))` for a clunky hack method?

Comment: @thelatemail: it won't work as expected if the items have different lengths, probably why `list` was used in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to extract the information that way once you've created `my.list`.

The underlying way `R` works is that expressions are not evaluated until they're needed; using `deparse(substitute())` will only work before the expression has been evaluated. So:

```
deparse(substitute(list(model.product, model.i, model.add)))
```

should work, while yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To save stuffing around, you could employ `mget` to collect your free-floating variables into a list with the names included:

```
one <- two <- three <- 1
result <- mget(c("one","two","three"))
result
#$one
#[1] 1
# 
#$two
#[1] 1
# 
#$three
#[1] 1
```

Then you can follow @DWin's suggestion:

```
names(result)
#[1] "one"   "two"   "three"
```