# deparse(substitute()) don't work as the way I want It to

Tags: r

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
data(iris)
L=list(data=iris)
print(deparse(substitute(L[[1]])))
[1] "L[[1]]"
```

I want the result to be "iris" instead of "L[[1]]", is there a way?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. `substitute` behaves as expected; it is neither a time machine nor a mind reading device. Once you have created your list like this, there is no way to know that its first component was once called "iris". If `substitute` would behave like you want, then with  `b <- 1; a <- b; deparse(substitute(b))` would return `1` instead of `b` which would be pretty catastrophic.

Answer (score 2):

```
L <- list(data=as.name("iris"))
L$data
```

And to actually retrieve the data:

```
eval(L$data)
```

But what you *should* be doing, rather than playing around with `eval` and `deparse`, is storing the name of the dataset along with its contents:

```
L <- list(iris=iris)
names(L)
L
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-list-objects-be-created-in-r-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-name/16951524#16951524