# How to print the names of dataframes in list with for loop?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes such as follows:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(x)
df2 <- data.frame(y)
x <- list(df1, df2)
```

I want to print the names of the dataframes in list `x` with a for loop such as this:

```
for (i in x) {
  deparse(substitute(x[i]))
}
```

But it doesn't work. My goal is to have the names of the dataframes printed out as characters such as this:

```
[1] df1
[2] df2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data.frames don't have "names". A variable can point to a data.frame, but a data.frame can exist without a name at all (like if you did `x <- list(data.frame(x), data.frame(y))`). So your data.frame isn't named `df1`; `df1` is a variable name that happens to point to a data.frame.

If you put a variable in a list, the value of the variable is placed in the list, not the variable name itself. So if you want to keep a name of the variable that originally held the object in the list, you'd need to store the name in the list. One common way to do that is

```
x <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
```

Then you can set the names with `names(x)`. If you want to see other ways to create lists that keep the object names, see the existing question: [Can lists be created that name themselves based on input object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names)

Answer (score 0):

There were some very helpful point: using `x <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)` to save the names of the data frames in the list and using the `names()` function. Here is the code I used to definitively print the names of the data frames in the list:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df1 <- data.frame(x)
df2 <- data.frame(y)
x <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
for (i in 1:2) {
print(as.character(names(x)[i]))
}
```

And this prints out the names of the data frames on the list.