# How to melt a list of data frames with the names of the data frames as a factor?

Tags: r

Given: a list of data frames with the same    number of columns, but varying number of rows.
Trying to get: a function that extracts the same column from all data frames and generates another column that labels from which data frame the common column came from.

My reasoning:

1. Use column I want and the name of the data frame to make a new data frame that has two columns: column of labels (name of the dataframe) and the column of interest
2. do this for every data frame.
3. rbind all dataframe
4. Make a function that does this for as many data frame inputs as requested

Given:

```r
a <- data.frame(V1=c(1:3),V2=c(1001:1003))
b <- data.frame(V1=c(1:5),V2=c(2001:2005))
```

What I want:

```r
rbind(data.frame(group="a",value=c(a$V2)),data.frame(group="b",value=c(b$V2)))
```

Effort to make a function that does this:

```r
my_fn <- function(...) {
  arg <- structure(list(...),names=as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L])
  do.call(rbind,lapply(arg,function(x) {data.frame(group="x",value=c(x$V2))})) %>% return
}
```

In the function I tried, I can almost get what I want, except `group="x"` is read as `"x"`. But I want it to read it as x=na   me of object in the list and then put " ".

Comment: You might use `data.table::rbindlist(list(a, b), idcol = "group")` or  `dplyr::bind_rows(list(a, b), .id = "group")`

Comment: Markus's suggestion combined with [something like this to preserve the names when you call `list()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951524/903061) should be pretty simple and work well

Comment: `tibble::lst` creates a list from variables where variable names become the names in the list, and `dplyr::bind_rows` has an argument `.id` that creates a column with the data frames' names as ID values