# How to name the elements of an unnamed list

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, brackets

I have a list that look like this:

```
setlist2 <- list(wsb_b6, wsb_id8)
[[1]]
[1] "Gm10116"       "Tpm3-rs7"      "Wdfy1"         "Rps3a2"        "AK157302"      "Gm6563"        
"Gm9825"        "Gm10259"       "Gm6768" 
[[2]]
 [1] "Gm6401"        "Ecel1"         "Hpca"          "Tmem176a"      "Lepr"          
"Baiap3"        "Fam183b"       "Vsx2"          "Vtn"
```

I need it to look like this:

```
$wsb_b6
    [1] "Gm10116"       "Tpm3-rs7"      "Wdfy1"         "Rps3a2"        "AK157302"      "Gm6563"        
    "Gm9825"        "Gm10259"       "Gm6768" 
$wsb_id8
    [1] "Gm6401"        "Ecel1"         "Hpca"          "Tmem176a"      "Lepr"          
"Baiap3"        "Fam183b"       "Vsx2"          "Vtn"
```

I know that by doing it manually I can achieve it but it is more that 100 each, there's got to be a better way

Comment: Do you want to replace the values in 2nd list with that of 1st list but then both the list would have same values?

Comment: Hello, the content of the lists are both fine. the problem is that instead of double brackets with numbers [[1]] and [[2]], like in the code I did, I need to have $name1 and $name2. I just don't know how to do that. I hope I made myself clearer. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr::lst`

```
setlist2 <- dplyr::lst(wsb_b6, wsb_id8)
```

Answer (score 2):

#I found that I had to unlist my  two previous lists

```
wsb_b6 <-wsb_b6[,1]
wsb_b6 <-unlist(wsb_b6)

wsb_id8 <-wsb_id8[,1]
wsb_id8 <- unlist(wsb_id8)
```

#And then list them again, but like this

```
   setlist2 <-list(wsb_b6=wsb_b6, wsb_id8= wsb_id8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a named list. Specifically, you want to create a named list where the names are taken from the names of the variables in the environment.

This is similar to this question: [Can lists be created that name themselves based on input object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I don't believe there is a simple function to do this in base R, but you can using the function `llist` from the package `Hmisc`:

```
library(Hmisc)

setlist2 <- llist(wsb_b6, wsb_id8)
```