# How to change a column name to the data frame variable name with lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to change the name of column 2 of multiple data frames to the name of variable defining each data frame. My function works on it's own, but when I use lapply, the column is renamed "x[[i]]" instead of "df1" or "df2". Thanks in advance!

```
    df1 = data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3), "b" = c(4,5,6))
    df2 = data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3), "b" = c(4,5,6))
    
    nameChange = function(x){
    name = deparse(substitute(x))
    colnames(x)[2] = name 
    return(x)
        }
    
    head(name(df)) # works
    lapply(list(df1, df2), nameChange ) # column is named "x[[i]]"
```

I tried using lapply, sapply, mapply, etc. and the USE.NAMES=T/F parameter but nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: What's the desired output here? You use `df` in the example but that's not defined. Note that `lapply` returns new values, it doesn't update data.frames in place. You can't really use non-standard evaluation with `lapply` like this because input is evaluated before being mapped over. If you need to store variables names in lists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names

Answer (score 2):

In your expression `lapply(list(df1, df2), nameChange)`, that first argument is evaulated to a list of dataframes, and the variable names `df1` and `df2` are lost:

```r
list(df1, df2)
```

```r
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

When you run `lapply()`, the function is applied to the *contents* of each list item. You can see internally that `lapply()` uses `[[` to subset the list item, which is why your `name` variable pulls `X[[i]]` from your `deparse(substitute())` operation.

```r
lapply(list(df1, df2), nameChange)
```

```r
[[1]]
  a X[[i]]
1 1      4
2 2      5
3 3      6

[[2]]
  a X[[i]]
1 1      4
2 2      5
3 3      6
```

I find myself constructing lists a lot, where the name of each list item has some important information. Instead of using `lapply()` to iterate through the list items, you can use `base::Map()` or `purrr::imap()` to iterate through both the list items and the list names. The way you specify arguments differ a bit. This solution would suggest naming your list items.

```r
# Make sure to store that naming information in the `names()` of the list
df_list <- list(
  df1 = df1,
  df2 = df2
)

# Function that takes the list item contents and the list item name
nameChangeNew <- function(df, name) {
  colnames(df)[2] <- name
  df
}

# For base::Map(), provide the lists (or vectors) to simultaneously iterate over
base::Map(nameChangeNew, df_list, names(df_list))

# For purrr::imap(), the list item contents and names are both provided to
# the function
purrr::imap(df_list, nameChangeNew)
```

Both of these functions give this output:

```r
$df1
  a df1
1 1   4
2 2   5
3 3   6

$df2
  a df2
1 1   4
2 2   5
3 3   6
```

Comment: Great answer! The only thing to add is that if you're doing the tidyverse route, `df_list<-dplyr::lst(df1, df2)` does the name parsing they're wanting without having to specify it as `df1 = df1`, etc.

Comment: Oh cool function and good suggestion. Thanks. Looks like we could replace `df_list` in those arguments with `dplyr::lst(df1, df2)` and avoid needing to separately define that list of dataframes.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was an eloquently written answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way how to do it with lapply is this one:

```
# Define a function 
change_second_column_name <- function(new_name, ...) {

  modified_dfs <- lapply(list(...), function(df) {
    # Change the name of the second column to the specified new_name
    colnames(df)[2] <- new_name
    return(df)
  })
  # Return the modified data frames as a list
  return(modified_dfs)
}

# Apply the function to change the name of the second column
change_second_column_name("Yay!", df1, df2)

[[1]]
  a Yay!
1 1    4
2 2    5
3 3    6

[[2]]
  a Yay!
1 1    4
2 2    5
3 3    6
```